# Is there a general [integer] solution for the family of hyperbolas with equation $x^2-xy-y^2=k$?

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory

I'm looking for integer solutions to a family of hyperbolas, with basic equation

$$x^2-xy-y^2=k.$$

Just wondering if there are any general solutions, or solutions given some restrictions on $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discriminant 5, class number 1. Irrelevant about $\pm k,$ as $-k$ is represented if and only if $k$ is. The only restriction is the prime factorization: if there is any prime $p|k$ with $p \equiv 2,3 \pmod 5,$ then the exponent of $p$ must be even. Same if there is more than one such prime, all even exponents.

And so on.

I have been polishing a program that gives the positive integers represented (integrally) by an indefinite form. One version gives all $a x^2 + b x y + c y^2,$ one version gives just those with $\gcd(x,y)=1.$

---

gcd(x,y) = 1

```
 Primitively represented positive integers up to  500

           1 =  1 
           5 = 5
          11 = 11
          19 = 19
          29 = 29
          31 = 31
          41 = 41
          55 = 5 * 11
          59 = 59
          61 = 61
          71 = 71
          79 = 79
          89 = 89
          95 = 5 * 19
         101 = 101
         109 = 109
         121 = 11^2
         131 = 131
         139 = 139
         145 = 5 * 29
         149 = 149
         151 = 151
         155 = 5 * 31
         179 = 179
         181 = 181
         191 = 191
         199 = 199
         205 = 5 * 41
         209 = 11 * 19
         211 = 211
         229 = 229
         239 = 239
         241 = 241
         251 = 251
         269 = 269
         271 = 271
         281 = 281
         295 = 5 * 59
         305 = 5 * 61
         311 = 311
         319 = 11 * 29
         331 = 331
         341 = 11 * 31
         349 = 349
         355 = 5 * 71
         359 = 359
         361 = 19^2
         379 = 379
         389 = 389
         395 = 5 * 79
         401 = 401
         409 = 409
         419 = 419
         421 = 421
         431 = 431
         439 = 439
         445 = 5 * 89
         449 = 449
         451 = 11 * 41
         461 = 461
         479 = 479
         491 = 491
         499 = 499


 Primitively represented positive integers up to  500

           1          -1          -1   original form 

jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

---

```
 ALL represented positive integers up to  500

           1 =  1 
           4 = 2^2
           5 = 5
           9 = 3^2
          11 = 11
          16 = 2^4
          19 = 19
          20 = 2^2 * 5
          25 = 5^2
          29 = 29
          31 = 31
          36 = 2^2 * 3^2
          41 = 41
          44 = 2^2 * 11
          45 = 3^2 * 5
          49 = 7^2
          55 = 5 * 11
          59 = 59
          61 = 61
          64 = 2^6
          71 = 71
          76 = 2^2 * 19
          79 = 79
          80 = 2^4 * 5
          81 = 3^4
          89 = 89
          95 = 5 * 19
          99 = 3^2 * 11
         100 = 2^2 * 5^2
         101 = 101
         109 = 109
         116 = 2^2 * 29
         121 = 11^2
         124 = 2^2 * 31
         125 = 5^3
         131 = 131
         139 = 139
         144 = 2^4 * 3^2
         145 = 5 * 29
         149 = 149
         151 = 151
         155 = 5 * 31
         164 = 2^2 * 41
         169 = 13^2
         171 = 3^2 * 19
         176 = 2^4 * 11
         179 = 179
         180 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 5
         181 = 181
         191 = 191
         196 = 2^2 * 7^2
         199 = 199
         205 = 5 * 41
         209 = 11 * 19
         211 = 211
         220 = 2^2 * 5 * 11
         225 = 3^2 * 5^2
         229 = 229
         236 = 2^2 * 59
         239 = 239
         241 = 241
         244 = 2^2 * 61
         245 = 5 * 7^2
         251 = 251
         256 = 2^8
         261 = 3^2 * 29
         269 = 269
         271 = 271
         275 = 5^2 * 11
         279 = 3^2 * 31
         281 = 281
         284 = 2^2 * 71
         289 = 17^2
         295 = 5 * 59
         304 = 2^4 * 19
         305 = 5 * 61
         311 = 311
         316 = 2^2 * 79
         319 = 11 * 29
         320 = 2^6 * 5
         324 = 2^2 * 3^4
         331 = 331
         341 = 11 * 31
         349 = 349
         355 = 5 * 71
         356 = 2^2 * 89
         359 = 359
         361 = 19^2
         369 = 3^2 * 41
         379 = 379
         380 = 2^2 * 5 * 19
         389 = 389
         395 = 5 * 79
         396 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 11
         400 = 2^4 * 5^2
         401 = 401
         404 = 2^2 * 101
         405 = 3^4 * 5
         409 = 409
         419 = 419
         421 = 421
         431 = 431
         436 = 2^2 * 109
         439 = 439
         441 = 3^2 * 7^2
         445 = 5 * 89
         449 = 449
         451 = 11 * 41
         461 = 461
         464 = 2^4 * 29
         475 = 5^2 * 19
         479 = 479
         484 = 2^2 * 11^2
         491 = 491
         495 = 3^2 * 5 * 11
         496 = 2^4 * 31
         499 = 499
         500 = 2^2 * 5^3


 ALL represented positive integers up to  500

           1          -1          -1   original form 

jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

---

Comment: So, for example, you can immediately say that $x^2-xy-y^2=35$ has no integer solutions, because $35=5^1 \cdot 7^1$? If so, what are references for the proof of this? Is it elementary?

Comment: Yes, elementary. Given $ax^2 + bxy+cy^2$ and $\Delta = b^2 - 4 a c,$ given prime $q$ with $(\Delta|q) = -1,$ then whenever $a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod q,$ then also $x,y \equiv 0 \pmod q.$ Does not apply this time, but primes $2$ and those that divide $\Delta$ are treated separately.

Answer (score 1):

You may convert this to the following equation:
$$(2x-y)^2-\mathbf{5} y^2=4k.$$
Let $X=2x-y$ and $Y=y$, then the equation becomes
$$X^2-\mathbf{5}Y^2=4k.$$
This is a Pell type equation. Now you can use the machinery to solve Pellian equations to answer this.

Comment: It is $(2x-y)^2 - 5 y^2 = 4 k$

Comment: @Will Jagy thanks for pointing it out. I have edited it.